# Is the render target view the only way to output data from pixel shader in DirectX?

Tags: gpu, directx-11, texture-mapping, render-to-texture, pixel-shader

**Purpose:**
I want to render an image in the screen and save it in my disk.

**Description:**
I have a render target view.
I have a input shader resource view with its texture (D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC).
I have a output shader resource view with its texture (D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT).
I have a auxiliar simple texture (D3D11_USAGE_STAGING).

The execution path is the following:

- Read input image in a texture.
- Bind the input texture view and output texture view, pixel shader, sampler and vertex shader.
- Run draw command.
- Copy output texture to auxiliar texture.
- Save auxiliar texture in a image. The image is empty.

**Question:**
How can I output an additional texture and still rendering on screen?

**Example code**

```
    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;

    // Create image texture to hold input image for unormalized values and CPU write/GPU read access
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC inputImageDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&inputImageDesc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
    inputImageDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    inputImageDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    inputImageDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE; // Needed for cpu write and gpu read
    inputImageDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    inputImageDesc.Width = width;
    inputImageDesc.Height = height;
    inputImageDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    inputImageDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    inputImageDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    inputImageDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC; // Needed for cpu write and gpu read

    result = engine.device()->CreateTexture2D(&inputImageDesc, nullptr, mInputTexture.GetAddressOf());
    if(result < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    result = engine.device()->CreateShaderResourceView(mInputTexture.Get(), nullptr, mInputView.GetAddressOf());
    if(result < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // Create image texture for unormalized values and only GPU access
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC gpuImageDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&gpuImageDesc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
    gpuImageDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    gpuImageDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;
    gpuImageDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0; // Needed for gpu read/write (cpu no access)
    gpuImageDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    gpuImageDesc.Width = width;
    gpuImageDesc.Height = height;
    gpuImageDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    gpuImageDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    gpuImageDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    gpuImageDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT; // Needed for gpu read/write (cpu no access)

    result = engine.device()->CreateTexture2D(&gpuImageDesc, nullptr, mOutputGpuTexture.GetAddressOf());
    if(result < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    result = engine.device()->CreateShaderResourceView(mOutputGpuTexture.Get(), nullptr, mOutputView.GetAddressOf());
    if(result < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    // Create image texture for unormalized values and only CPU read access
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC cpuImageDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&cpuImageDesc, sizeof(D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC));
    mOutputGpuTexture->GetDesc(&cpuImageDesc);
    cpuImageDesc.BindFlags       = 0;
    cpuImageDesc.MiscFlags       = 0;
    cpuImageDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ; // Needed for cpu read
    cpuImageDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING; // Needed for cpu read

    result = engine.device()->CreateTexture2D(&cpuImageDesc, nullptr, mOutputCpuTexture.GetAddressOf());
    if(result < 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
```

```
struct PixelInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float2 coord : TEXCOORDIN;
    float2 coordOut : TEXCOORDOUT;
};

Texture2D<float4> gInputTexture : register(t0);
SamplerState gSampleType : register(s0);
RWTexture2D<float4> gOutputTexture : register(t1);

float4 main(PixelInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    gOutputTexture[input.coordOut] = float4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    float4 inputPixel = float4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    inputPixel.rgb = gInputTexture.Sample(gSampleType, input.coord).rgb;
    return inputPixel;
}
```

```
    engine.context()->CopyResource(mOutputCpuTexture.Get(), mOutputGpuTexture.Get());
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedImgData;
    ZeroMemory(&mappedImgData, sizeof(D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE));
    int32_t result = engine.context()->Map(mOutputCpuTexture.Get(), 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mappedImgData);
    if(result < EC_SUCCESS)
    {
        ERROR_MSG(result);
        return EC_COULD_NOT_MAP_RESOURCE_TEXTURE;
    }

    // Copy the less bytes possible, avoiding out of bounds.
    const uint32_t bytesPerRow = std::min(rowPitch, mappedImgData.RowPitch);

    uint8_t* textureData = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(mappedImgData.pData);
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < height; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(dst, textureData, bytesPerRow);
        textureData += mappedImgData.RowPitch;
        dst += rowPitch;
    }
    engine.context()->Unmap(mOutputCpuTexture.Get(), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did to fix this was add a compute shader as intermediary, in that way I read a RWTexture (DEFAULT) with another texture (STAGING) and also another one to read the back buffer.